# Annotation @Basic to transient variables

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, annotations, hql

I am having a POJO class which consists of:
- persistent properties,
- transient properties.

While writing HQL I considered both: persistent and transient properties.
I.e. HQL like `select persistent_properties,transient_prop from Pojo_classname`

is it correct?

Can I write `@Basic` annotation to transient variables?

Comment: Why would you like to create a query for fields which doesn't exist in the database (are transient)?

Comment: yeah! actually I'm having two transient properties which are having @Formula(value="select ...."). and thanx Piotr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not correct. A HQL query translates to SQL. An `@Transient` property is not in the database, so the SQL query won't be able to query over this property.

`@Basic` and `@Transient` are contradictory. The first one tells "this property is persistent" and the second one tells "This property is not persistent".

If you're talking about the Java `transient` keyword, and not about the `@Transient` annotation, then yes, a `transient` field may be queried and annotated with `@Basic`. The `transient` keyword has nothing to do with persistence, only with binary serialization of the object.

Comment: thank you JB but can you tell the difference in functionality using both transient keyword and @Transient annotation?

Comment: I told you in my answer. @Transient means "this field is not a persistent field". It's a JPA annotation. transient means "when serializing this object, this field should not be ignored". It's a Java keyword.

Comment: JB Nizet, are you sure about this? JPA 2.0 Spec: " All **non-transient** instance variables that are not annotated with the 'Transient' annotation are persistent.". If I add 'transient' keyword before my field, it will not be persisted and appropriate column will not be created when schema generation is used. Following quote "Mapping annotations must not be applied to fields or properties that are transient **or** `Transient`."